# Extracting random nodes in a graph using an attributes

Tags: python, random, networkx

I have a networkX graph where every node has an attribute.

I need to extract nodes based on a numerical attribute made in the range [0,inf] to create edges.
I tried using `random.choice(G.nodes(), p)` with p=attribute/(sum of the attributes in the graph).

The problem is that everytime i extract a node to create the edge my attribute change (for example let's say the `attribute+=1`) so I need to update all the probabilities because also the sum increases by 1.

For example I could have a graph with `G.nodes(data=True)={1:{att=10},2:{att=5}, 3:{att=2}}`
So `p=[10/17, 5/17, 2/17]`.

If I extract for example 1 at the first extraction my graph will be `G.nodes(data=True)={1:{att=11},2:{att=5}, 3:{att=2}}` and `p=[11/18, 5/18, 2/18]`.

Now, because i have more than a thousand graph and for every one of them I need to do a 50000 for clause that create edges,  it's not computationally feasible to update all the probability every time i create an edge.

Is there a way to just use the node's attribute or to not calculate my probability every time?

Comment: Presumably there is a way.

Comment: The attribute changing every time you extract a node - is that something you don't want to happen?

Comment: It is best you provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can understand the problem better

Comment: Nono it's important that happens, anyway I think I've solved the problem using numpy, I will post in an answer

Answer (score 0):

By using numpy array I have done this:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
G.nodes[1]["att"]=10
G.nodes[2]["att"]=5
G.nodes[3]["att"]=2
dict={}
for i in G.nodes():
    dict[i]=G.nodes[i]["att"]
extracted=random.chance(G.nodes(),p=np.fromiter(dict.values(),dtype="float")/np.sum(np.fromiter(dict.values(),dtype="float")))
```

When extracted (for example node 1)  `G.nodes[1]["att"]+=1` and nothing else need to be updated